# Limits from the right and left

Tags: limits

Evaluate the limits below,

$$\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{x-2}{x^2-4} $$ and
$$\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{x-2}{x^2-4} $$

Alright, I know that the limit from the right will equal positive infinity and the left will equal the negative infinity, by graphing.

Now, how do I solve this problem without graphing??

1)How would I solve if it approaches from both direction? Do I substitute the value?

2)How would I solve from the right/left side? How would I know without graphing?

I want to use this as an example to all my related questions.
How would I solve for both side, and right/left side without graphing?
Will there be any certain value showing later?
Are there any useful theorems?

---

After factorized into,

$$ \frac{1}{x+2}$$

How is answer going to be different when approaching from right and left? or both sides?

Comment: Hm,

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2 - 4} = \frac{1}{x+2}$$

Comment: factor the denominator. Remember that (a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the graph you mentioned. The +/- infinity limits you described occur at $x=-2$, not $x=2$.

Comment: I think you should rather GRAPH the function _before_ you declare you know the limits and ask how to calculate them _without_ graphing... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the limit exists

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x-2}{x^2-4}=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)}=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{1}{x+2}=\frac14.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint;**
$\displaystyle a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$

Answer (score 1):

HiNt:

$$\frac{x-2}{x^2-4} = \frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)} = \frac{1}{x+2}$$